# ggplot - plotting CDF from percentiles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a dataframe that holds processed CDF data points ( percentiles) from a very large dataset coming from a data warehouse like below

```
text <- "
name,var,value
a,0.01,0.27
b,0.01,0.24
c,0.01,0.25
a,0.05,0.48
b,0.05,0.43
c,0.05,0.48
a,0.1,0.62
b,0.1,0.57
c,0.1,0.64
a,0.25,0.93
b,0.25,0.88
c,0.25,0.99
a,0.5,1.41
b,0.5,1.39
c,0.5,1.52
a,0.75,2.12
b,0.75,2.08
c,0.75,2.28
a,0.9,3.11
b,0.9,3
c,0.9,3.29
a,0.95,3.92
b,0.95,3.75
c,0.95,4.09
a,0.99,5.9
b,0.99,5.65
c,0.99,6.04
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Each of the `var` values like `0.01, 0.05, 0.10` etc. refer to 1st percentile, 5th percentile, 10th percentile and so on. I need to create a CDF 'like' plot using this data for the three `name`s `a,b,c` in a single plot. How do I got about it.

**Update**:

Plot using the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48346465/3206440) is added here - this however doesn't create a line ( preferably a smooth one) as intended.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in functions for CDF plots (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ecdf.html), but I find ggplot nicer-looking and more intuitive

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = value, color = name)) + geom_path()
```

There are lots of customizations you can add to this, but I'll only mention one:  add `+ geom_point()` to the ggplot statement to mark the measurement intervals.  If you have other style preferences, reply and I (or somebody more qualified) will do our best

Comment: I added `geom_point()` to this. This gives the points, however I'm not able to get a line joining them. How do I get that part preferably a smooth line ? My result plot is included in the updated original question.

Comment: got this working by changing the `var` to `numeric` from `chr` !!